# Can someone point me toward a plugin for this specific featured content display?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

A client would like a featured content display that looks exactly like the one here: [kroq.radio.com](http://kroq.radio.com/).  It's not a slideshow - it's tabbed navigation with pictures through four featured posts. As far as I can see it's just done with CSS, not JS. (Could be wrong.)

I started searching in the WP.org plugin repository but as I wasn't even sure what to call this thing, I felt like I wasn't making much headway. The closest thing I found to what I wanted was Slidedeck which I might go with, but if my client really wants it styled like the KROQ one (with the side arrows and such), I'm not sure if that'd be possible (and if it was I *am* confident it'd be a huge PITA.)

So my questions are: 1) does anybody know of a plugin that would copy or approximate this display thingy and 2) even if you don't, what the search terms would I use to search one up?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't dive too deep, but it seem like it was done with [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

I helped with similar layout some time ago at Hybrid forums, here is resulting post [WordPress Feature Posts Slider Using jQuery](http://krogsgard.com/2010/08/tutorial-wordpress-feature-posts-slider-using-jquery/)

For the record I think it is variation of `slider` and it is ok to call it that. `Slider` plus `tabs` are good keywords for search.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the link, Rarst.  Tracy, simulating what is on the radio website is pretty simple via the code I posted.  You would only have to change the stylesheet from the dowload I provide.  You could even get away with using CSS3 on the side arrows and gradient as long as you don't care about IE 6.  I too could never find a WP plugin that I liked enough to fit the bill.

I've already configured this thing about 3 different ways, so feel free to get in touch with me via my contact page if you need some help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of HTML / CSS and jquery. I've seen a few themes that implement it (Elegant Themes being one of them, an example here: http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/glow/)  I don't know of any plugins off hand that do that, you'd probably have to code it.